# Using multiple nested-modules in apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am creating a set of modules (widgets) with apostrophe-cms (2.x).
Now I want to create different nested widgets, to use some of the modules e.g. in a 2-column layout.
I followed the tutorial for nested-widgets https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/layout-widgets.html and created a simple two column layout:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Two Column Layout',
  contextualOnly: true,
  addFields: [{
      name: 'columnLeft',
      type: 'area',
      label: 'Left Area',
    },
    {
      name: 'columnRight',
      type: 'area',
      label: 'Right Area',
    }
  ]
};
```

In part this works. I can add other widgets inside the two areas and the html gets correctly built.
The problem comes when I use other widgets below the two column layout. Taking a look at the Inspector, I see that all widgets **below** get built inside the two-column apos-area-widget-wrapper . When I only want to delete the two column widget then, I also delete all modules below. (See image Link)

[Chrome Inspector, wrong nesting of widgets inside the two column widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxrYu.png)

Am I missing something or does the nested layout somehow miss its closing  tag, so everything gets pulled into it?

(Update): Trying to narrow down the problem: I can add new (non-layout-only) modules below, they appear correct. As soon as I try to add another layout widget, I cannot do anything with it as it does not save any information.

(Update): GitHub Project for demonstration: https://github.com/raphaelurban/apostrophe-test

Comment: Please link to a project in GitHub that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sounds like broken markup extending your areas beyond their intended scope but a repo would be helpful

Comment: I created a small repo to display the error here: https://github.com/raphaelurban/apostrophe-test . The problem arises as soon as I use the "two-column" widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting exactly your behavior but indeed the template for `accordion-widgets` does not properly close it's markup. The leak could affect different browsers differently, in Chrome I'm getting some broken stacking.

Comment: Ah found it, so it is nothing with the nested widgets themselves, but I forgot the closing </div>. I changed it in the markup, now it works fine. Thanks